# Ao Maximizar uma pagina em wpf c# ela sobrepõe a barra de tarefas do windows

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou criando um projeto em wpf e precisei substituir os botões de minimizar, maximizar e fechar, segue condição utilizada:

```
if (sender == checklist.btnMaximizar)
{
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
else if (sender == checklist.btnMinimizar)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
else if (sender == checklist.btnFechar)
{
    InformacaoSistema.FECHAR_CHECKLIST = false;
    Close();
}
```

Mas quando maximizo a aplicação sobrepõe a barra de tarefas dificultando a utilização, todo os exemplo que pesquisei na internet solucionava problemas em windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente o seguinte:

```
MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
```

Basicamente estamos a limitar o máximo de altura e largura do `Form`.

Comment: Perfeito João Martins, setei essas duas propriedades antes de mudar o WindowState e funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Se a solução funcionou, marque a resposta como correta :)